# add count in log file python 3.6.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, logfiles

I am working on writing a log file (first time still new to programming as a whole) and I want to have the log file write the number of records inserted into a mysql database and a message.
eg. `2018-03-15 09:09:59 - 30 records entered in the database` 
I have two functions, one is the actual write function to the log file and the other is to send the message once the records have been entered.

**write to log function**

```
def write_log():
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

hf = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(logdir, logfile), 'a')
hf.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
hf.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hf)
return True
```

**executes query function**

```
def execute(con):
sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`value`, `value`, `value`)
    cursor = con.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    con.commit()
    logging.info(count + 'records entered in the database.') # Obviously this is where I'm wrong.

except pyodbc.Error:
    con.rollback()
    logging.error('Could not enter records into the database.')


cursor.close()
con.close()
return True
```

and then I call the functions in another script. It all works fine but clearly the count and messages aren't being written the way I want them to be like this `2018-03-15 09:09:59 - 30 records entered in the database`

I have split the count variable and then the message like this:

```
logging.info(count)
logging.info('records entered in the database.')
```

but that doesn't produce the right output for obvious reasons. I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: what does the count variable contain? Its not clear if you want a way to create the count variable or a way to include the count variable into the log message

Comment: my apologies, I have already created the count variable, I want to include the count variable into the log message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string format`:

```
logging.info('{0} records entered in the database.'.format(count))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, could I ask, If I wanted to have this work inside a different script would it still work the same? eg. if i had the same two functions in a script called example1.py and wanted to call the count variable inside another function in a script called example2.py can I still use the same solution?.

Comment: `logger.info` doesn't provide a well-support for string made by `+`, it has nothing to do with the file name. If you want to `logger.info` a variable string, use string format, don't use `+`.